# PyQt and 32-bit Enthought ipython in Mountain Lion

Tags: python, pyqt, ipython, homebrew

I installed the free (32-bit) Enthought Python [distribution](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd_free.php) on Mac OsX Mountain Lion. In order to run ipython's Qt console I also installed PyQt using homebrew (brew install pyqt).

It turns out that PyQt is compiled for 64-bit architecture, which is incompatible with my Enthought distribution. Enthought actually cautions against using their 64-bit distribution since wxPython is missing.

Is there a way to compile PyQt for 32-bit?

Comment: you just need to add the `--arch i386` flag when [compiling pyqt4](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/installation.html#building-pyqt). or you could use the builds from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqtx/files/), they seem to be built for 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: EPD just got a new release (renamed to Canopy), which is now 64b by default, so this shouldn't come up so much.